# Python - PyQt window became unmovable after adding some codes

Tags: python, pyqt4

i am trying to set a window(i used QLabel) to look like an image in PyQt4
so i wrote this code :

```
    self.background_update = QPixmap(":/work/window.png")
    update.setPixmap(self.background_update)
    update.resize(self.background.width(), self.background.height())
    update.show()
```

then i tried to remove the window default action bar and show it transparent to look good so i added

```
    update.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    update.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
```

everything worked fine but the problem is : the window now became unmovable by using the mouse (like any normal window)

what should i add to fix this ? and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what platform you are on, but on Linux you can move any window by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> and dragging with the mouse. But if that doesn't work, you can quite easily implement similar functionality in your own code.

Here's a simple demo (left-click and drag):

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setGeometry(600, 400, 200, 200)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.move(event.globalPos() - self._startpos)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self._startpos = event.pos()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @Malekpython. As I said: if alt+mouse-drag doesn't work, try my script, which will work. Did you actually try it? And just to be clear: my script uses left-click and drag, not alt + drag.